# combo box in spring web mvc

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using spring web mvc for my app's UI part..

By using following code, i am getting List Box where i can select more then 1 value..

```
<form:select path="domainsList">
<form:options items="${domainsList}" itemValue="domain" itemLabel="domain"/>
</form:select>
```

But I need a drop down combo box...

Can any one suggest how can i convert it to combo box ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you please be more clear? There is no such thing as "combo box" (an editable dropdown) in HTML and starters often confuse this term. Do you really need an editable dropdown? If so, how editable should it be? By typing the first item as if it is an input text? Or by having a two <select multiple> elements and a bunch of buttons which moves the selected items from left to right and vice versa?

Comment: Hi, BalusC.. I just a simple dropdown list (like combo box) where user can select only 1 value, that's it... From above code that i have posted in my questions, gives me a list box in which user can select more then 1 value, that i don't want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, for asking silly question.. But i got working combo box by following code :

```
<form:select path="domainsList" multiple="false" size="1">
<form:options items="${domainsList}" itemValue="domain" itemLabel="domain"/>
</form:select>
</form:form>
```

Comment: This is not a combo box. This is a dropdown. A combo box is an editable dropdown and such thing does by default not exist in HTML (and thus also not in the component based MVC frameworks providing basic HTML components) :)

Answer (score 3):

Spring will decide the type of field to use depending on the type of data, so if the 'path' field is an object, it will show a dropdown, but if it is a "list" (array, collection, ...) it will show a list, unless you specify multiple="false"

This will show a list with multiple selection:

```
Integer[] ids;
<form:select path="ids" items="${whatever}" />
```

This will show a dropdown with single selection:

```
Integer id;
<form:select path="id" items="${whatever}" />
```

This will also show a dropdown with single selection:

```
Integer[] ids;
<form:select path="ids" items="${whatever}" multiple="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The spring "form:select" tag just wraps the HTML select element. It also has an attribute *size* which has to be set to a value of *1* to let this selection become rendered as a combobox (in most browsers).

this is basic HTML:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-size-SELECT

```
<form:select path="domainsList" size="1">
   <form:options items="${domainsList}" itemValue="domain" itemLabel="domain"/>
</form:select>
```

@Nirmal please check your markup. This should work.

```
<html>
    <SELECT name="selection" size="1">
        <OPTION selected label="none" value="none">None</OPTION>
        <OPTION label="1" value="1">OPTION 1</OPTION>
        <OPTION label="2" value="2">OPTION 2</OPTION>
        <OPTION label="3" value="3">OPTION 3</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, squiddle.. thanks for reply.. But from your ans, i am not getting a pure combo box where user can select only 1 option from given list.. Can you please recheck your answer ?

Comment: oh, this is just a drop-down list not a combobox (there is no such thing in html, yet)
and multiple selection is normally not possible with a drop-down.

Comment: Sorry boss for inconvenience.. I got the solution by just adding multiple="false" property...

Comment: @squiddle: Multiple selection is certainly possible using the 'multiple' attribute.

Comment: @BalusC but not as a drop-down. it will be rendered as a list (at least here in Chromium, Firefox and Safari on Mac OS). In Firefox even as just a list with one row, which makes it quite unusable.